# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls' not working in Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm using Django 1.9

```
 from django.contrib admin
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from slack.views import DRSWebhookTransactionView, DRSMessageView
 from django.urls import path 

 api_patterns = ([
        path('web/', DRSWebhookTransactionView.as_view()),
        path('events/', DRSMessageView.as_view()),
    ], 'api')


 urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('api/v1/', include(api_patterns)),
]
```

After running python manage.py runserver:

```
from django.urls import (  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'
```

I'm getting this error after I tried including path. If I don't include path it's not showing the error for the 'path', it's still showing the same error. Can someone tell how can I rewrite this program? and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Django 1.9 doesn't have `path`, it was introduced in 2.0.

Comment: Can I replace it with some other function?

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 is end of life and does not receive security updates. If you can't upgrade to the latest version, then the upgrade to Django 1.11 LTS should be simpler, and it is still supported for another year.

Comment: from django.urls import path   --> path is available
 for django1.9

Comment: Does Django 1.11 support HSStoreField?

Comment: [`HStoreField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.HStoreField) was added in Django 1.8, so it's available in all versions since then, including 1.11.

Answer (score 3):

for django 1.9

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: yeah I did that but still getting the same error. It's now even showing that I have not included a include and path variable.

Comment: Note that the line from the error message `from django.urls import (  # noqa` is not the same as in your question. If you still get the same error, then either you haven't saved your changes and restarted the server, or you have another incorrect import that you have to fix. The full traceback will show you where the problem is.

Comment: I did all those things but still getting the same error. Do you think I should make a different file of urls.py in the local app and register the router there?

Comment: Okay so I'm not able to import classes from views.py. That's why I'm getting this problem.